# I need to set a value to NULL after using it to update another value

Tags: sql, oracle, updates

I have something like this :

```
UPDATE table1 SET variable2 = variable3 WHERE variable2 IS NULL;
UPDATE table1 SET variable1 = variable2 WHERE variable1 IS NULL;
```

The problem I have is that when I change for exemple variable2 with the value of variable3 I want the variable3 to becom NULL.

I think we have Oracle 12 and I thnk that in theory something like that should work :

```
UPDATE table1 SET variable2 = variable3, variable3 = NULL WHERE variable2 IS NULL;
```

But our DBA don't want us to use this ....

Any idea ?

Thanks !

Comment: Did your DBA give a reason not to use this? Does the SQL you posted match what you sent over to DBA, you may have simplified it for SO?

Comment: The respective column may have intentionally been set to not accept nulls.  There's a plethora of reasons why the DBA restricted it; I'd certainly reach out to your DBA for this reason.

Comment: He said that yes it may work right now but if we change version of Oracle it may not work anymore or something like that. And no I didn't simplified the code. The point is to always have a value in variable1 before we have a value in 2 or 3, same principle with 2 ...

Comment: You keep using `variableX` which implies that these are local variables.  Some of these must be database columns not local variables or the SQL would be invalid.  Is the DBA's objection that you're really talking about variables so there is no need to use an `UPDATE` statement to modify them?  Or are you actually talking about changing data in different columns?

Comment: Sorry my bad, yes they are database columns where 1, 2 and 3 are of the same types and accept NULL. .. And DBA is on vacation for 2 weeks ....

Comment: It's extremely unlikely the update statement you came up with would stop working in future versions of Oracle, since it would mean a fundamental change to how Oracle does updates (and would impact triggers, etc). Oracle keeps two records when DML is performed - and :old and :new record that keeps hold of the prior and latest contents of the row. In the `set` clause of the update statement, Oracle uses information from the :old record to determine the values, and the :new records would contain the results after the update is performed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Boneist said in the comment, it's extremely unlikely that Oracle will change the `UPDATE` statement on such a fundamental level for your `UPDATE` not to work.

What's more, one can't even start to think that way. As no one really knows what the changes will/might be, the BEST thing (and only thing) surely is to continue developing in the way that is best on the current version.

Your `UPDATE` is good.

The only addition I'd make is checking if the column you're copying from really has any value. That would avoid "updating" rows where there is nothing to update (and perhaps mess up your audit columns through triggers, if you have those implemented):

```
UPDATE table1 
   SET variable2 = variable3 
     , variable3 = NULL
 WHERE variable2 IS NULL
   AND variable3 IS NOT NULL;

UPDATE table1 
   SET variable1 = variable2 
     , variable2 = NULL
 WHERE variable1 IS NULL
   AND variable2 IS NOT NULL;
```